# Why is my read in of data taking so long?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, import, data

I'm just trying to read in some data before I do some calculations.  The data set is over 200,000 values that look like this:

> [image: Blockquote]

Here is the code I am using:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

Hrank = Flatten[Import["C:\\Projects\\Points_Analysis\\H_Rank.txt", "Table"]];
HighRank = Cases[Hrank, x_?NumericQ /; x <= Mean[Hrank] + 3*StandardDeviation[Hrank] && 
 x > Mean[Hrank] - 3*StandardDeviation[Hrank]];
```

It's just determining the values that lie within 3 sigma of the mean, but the calculation is taking hours (so far 6!) and doesn't seem to want to end.  Could someone please tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code is recalculating `Mean[Hrank]` and `StandardDeviation[Hrank]` with each comparison, making it extremely slow. Store them separately, and the calculation becomes much faster. I simulated an `Hrank` vector using:

```
Hrank = RandomInteger[{0, 1000}, 200000];
```

And then did:

```
mean = Mean[Hrank];
stddev = StandardDeviation[Hrank];
HighRank = 
   Cases[Hrank, 
    x_?NumericQ /; 
     x <= mean + 3*stddev && x > mean - 3*stddev]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

All as one cell, so that it would automatically update if `Hrank` changed. This gave a timing (via `AbsoluteTiming`) of 3.421 seconds (on my system) for 200,000 elements. Using a smaller sample, it appears that this should give exactly the same results as the original code, as at no point would `Hrank` be altered during this.

It's possible to go faster than this using `Compile` and some cleverness. Since it's actually more elegant than using `Cases`, it's presented below:

Define a family of test functions (`testf[m,s]`) below:

```
testf[m_, s_] := 
  Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x <= m + 3 s && x > m - 3 s, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];
```

Note that `testf[m,s]` returns a compiled function object which tests a real number as to whether it is within 3 standard deviations (`True`) or not (`False`). This is then used with `Pick` to pick out the final set:

```
HighRank2 = Pick[Hrank, testf[mean, stddev][Hrank]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

It is roughly 200 times faster (on my system, probably faster still if you have more than 8 threads available) than the above version using `Cases`.

@Shadowray provides an even faster version utilizing `UnitStep`, `RealAbs`, and numericizing the input list to machine numbers before hand. Some cursory examination suggests the results match identically in at least most cases, so I'll preserve it here below:

```
threeSigmaFilter[list_] := 
 With[{nlist = N[list]}, 
  Pick[list, 
   UnitStep[
    RealAbs[nlist - Mean[nlist]] - 3 StandardDeviation[nlist]], 0]]
```

This centers the whole data list on the mean, takes the absolute value of that, and subtracts 3 standard deviations. If this result is less than 0, then `UnitStep` returns 0, and `Pick`'s 3rd argument tells `Pick` to keep it from the original `list`. It doesn't seem like `Compile` can be used to further speed this up. This isn't very surprising, `UnitStep` and `RealAbs` (or `Abs`, not much performance difference there it seems) are already `Listable` and quite fast as built-ins, and there is a time overhead to compiling a function.

Comment: Can be further optimized to something like: `threeSigmaFilter[list_] := With[{nlist=N[list]}, Pick[list, UnitStep[RealAbs[nlist-Mean[nlist]] - 3 StandardDeviation[nlist]], 0] ]`

Comment: @Shadowray Thanks for pointing that out. I was hesitant to numericize the list because it introduces a little bit of inaccuracy, but it is fair to say that it's quite a bit faster. I'm always surprised at how fast `UnitStep` is too.

Comment: I know we're not supposed to express thanks, but I just wanted to let both of you know how much I appreciated your solutions!